# Count distinct values from query result

Tags: mysql

I have a query `SELECT COUNT(TeamID) AS "Team size" FROM tblteamplayers GROUP BY TeamID` which returns the numbers of players in each team like this:

```
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 1 |
+---+
```

But I need to count how many items each team size is listed in this example here:

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |
+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group again in an outer query:

```
SELECT `Team size`, COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT   COUNT(*) AS `Team size`
  FROM     tblteamplayers
  GROUP BY TeamID
) t GROUP BY `Team size`
```